# Google App Engine php include/require directive

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Google App Engine php include/require directive problem.

FILE 1: app.yaml

```
application: myapp

version: 1

runtime: php

api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /stylesheets

  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images

  static_dir: images

- url: /myIncludes

  script: form.php

- url: /.*

  script: HelloWorld.html.php
```

FILE 2: php.ini

```
; This is a simple php.ini file.

; It indicates my desire to use php’s include and require directives.

google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets=‘bucket1’
```

FILE 3: form.php

```
The php code in this file simply echoes an html form.
```

FILE 4: HelloWorld.html.php

```
    <?php

    echo '

        <html>

        <head>

        <style type="text/css">

        body {background-color:red;}

        </style>

        </head><body>

        <table>

        <tr>

        <td>My First Cloud App</td>

        </tr></table>

        ';


        include 'gs://bucket1/form.php';


        echo '

    </body>

    </html>

    ';

?>
```

The name of my bucket in Google Cloud Storage is bucket1. bucket1 contains form.php. All permissions for both the bucket and its object have been set to **Read** for everyone.
I am able to use all the appropriate **PHP** file functions. However, I am unable to use the php directives `include` and **require**.

When I ran myapp, it displays `My First Cloud App` with a red background but it does not display the html in “form.php.” I get the following error in my Google Account Log file:

```
2013-11-19 01:44:20.209
PHP Warning:  include(gs://bucket1/form.php): failed to open stream: "\google\appengine\ext\cloud_storage_streams\CloudStorageStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in /base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.335363258528205/HelloWorld.html.php on line 74
W 2013-11-19 01:44:20.209
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'gs://bucket1/form.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.335363258528205/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk') in /base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.335363258528205/HelloWorld.html.php on line 74
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I want to know, why did you store that .php file in bucket??? you can simply keep it in folder where your `helloworld.html.php` is... 
one more thing... what kind of file is that `helloworld.html.php`

Comment: No, store it in the folder where `helloworld.html.php` is stored and than you can include in as many file you want.....You dont need bucket for this purpose...

Comment: The .php file is in a bucket because I want to include it in multiple files. Documentation available on developers.google.com specifies that the only way one can include a file in multiple other files is by storing that file in a bucket. Let me say this differently: I am going to create several directories. Each directory is going to have various php scripts. I would like each of the scripts to have access to form.php. Therefore, I have to use the include/require directives. Hence, form.php MUST be located in a bucket. helloworld.html.php is a php file. You may ignore the .html portion.

Comment: According to documentation on developers.google.com, in order to include a file in multiple files, you MUST use the following code:       include 'gs://your_bucket/your_file'. It is impossible to include it in files located in multiple directories by storing it within one directory. Looking at the above line of code, you can tell that the file to be included MUST be located within a bucket.

Comment: Hey, no matter how many directory you create, still you dont need bucket for it... 

See let me give you a Example... 
Your form.php is in `/form.php`
and you want to include it in `/folder1/file1.php`
then in `file1.php` you can write `include('../form.php');`
and you want to include it in `/folder2/file2.php`
then in `file2.php` you can write `include('../form.php');`
if you have file in root foler itself `/helloworld.html.php`
then simple write `include('form.php');`
I had tested this in many app of GAE

Comment: Mr. Mohd Suleman, thank you so so much. include('form.php'); works perfectly fine. I wonder why google does not mention this code on their site. Perhaps they want people to spend some money purchasing bucket space. I spent almost 2 entire days struggling with this. Thanks again. You've just made my day.

Comment: Glad that I helped... :) I had posted answer for this question, so that other people may take help from it.....

Comment: According to this documentation page, you need to set "allow_url_include 1" in `php.ini`


https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what the actual answer is - can the answerer post it - or if that's already happened, can the OP accept it?

Answer (score 2):

No need of uploading form.php in the bucket...

No matter how many directory you create, still you dont need bucket for it... 
See let me give you a Example...

Your `form.php` is in `/form.php`

and you want to include it in `/folder1/file1.php` 
then in file1.php you can write `include('../form.php');`

and you want to include it in `/folder2/file2.php`
then in file2.php you can write `include('../form.php');`

if you have file in root foler itself `/helloworld.html.php`
then simple write `include('form.php');`

Answer (score 0):

CyberBoy is correct that you do not need to put form.php in GCS bucket to include it. I'm not sure which part of the documentation you're referring to, but there're really very few and specific reasons why you'd want to include PHP script directly from GCS.

Comment: I found the relevant bit of documentation
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/advanced

Comment: "Using PHP include and require: 

To help maintain the security of your application, the ability to include or require from a Cloud Storage file is disabled by default, but you can enable it, as follows: 

To include or require PHP code from Google Cloud Storage in your application, you must specify which buckets contain those files using the google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets directive in your php.ini file."